# How to setup unit tests for Nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vitest

I created a new Nuxt3 app via `npx nuxi init <project-name>` and want to add unit tests. Based on [the docs for testing](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/testing#testing) I called `npm install -D @nuxt/test-utils vitest` and started with `./pages/foo.spec.ts`

```
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";
import { setup } from "@nuxt/test-utils";

describe("Suite", async () => {
  await setup();

  it("passes", () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When calling `vitest --run` I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
 ❯ setupVitest ../../node_modules/@nuxt/test-utils/dist/index.mjs:138:10
    137|     setTestContext(void 0);
    138|   };
    139|   const afterAll = async () => {
       |     ^
    140|     if (ctx.serverProcess) {
    141|       setTestContext(ctx);
 ❯ Module.setup ../../node_modules/@nuxt/test-utils/dist/index.mjs:197:3
 ❯ pages/foo.spec.ts:5:3
```

I also thought about calling `nuxt test` instead but get this error

```
Listening http://[::]:38515
[error] ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Suites 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
[error]
[error]  FAIL  pages/foo.spec.ts [ pages/foo.spec.ts ]
[error] Error: No test suite found in file /home/.../pages/foo.spec.ts
```

Maybe my setup is wrong. I wasn't able to find information about

- Where to put the tests?
- How to call the tests via npm scripts?

Comment: welcome to a long and painfull journey with vitest and nuxt. This might help you [Elk Zone as testing example](https://github.com/elk-zone/elk/tree/main/) and [Nuxt Vitest](https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-vitest). As for your questions: I put my tests inside `/tests/unit/` for unit tests and `/tests/nuxt/` for e2e tests. But yours is fine too. Tests are run with `npm run vitest`. Whats in your `vitest.config`?

Comment: thanks, I didn't create a `vitest.config` yet, will do. If `npm run vitest` is fine, what is `nuxt test` for?

Comment: I don't know nuxt test and it's the first time I hear it. I can't find it in the docs. `npx nuxi test --help` says it runs tests. Stick with vitest. It is the way to go.

Comment: my `vitest.config` currently contains `export default defineConfig({ test: {} })` but the error remains. Do I have to use the third party module https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-vitest ?

Comment: No. I was able to get it working by just following the docs you provided. I came up with nuxt vitest later. Maybe this helps you: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-bjyxnr)